# SysVinit service runs differently from the script itself

Tags: debian, services, sysvinit

I'm using Linux Deploy on Android and trying to create a service for SysVinit. The distribution I use is Debian buster. I wrote the following script. The problem is: when running it as a script itself, it works perfectly, but not as a service. It works if I run `service clash start` or `service clash stop`, but not `service clash restart`. SysVinit runs it on boot correctly.  So the only issue is with the `restart` case. It runs `stop` then exits without touching the following `start`. What should I do to solve this problem?

```
  1 #!/bin/zsh
  2 # Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
  3 # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
  4 # description: Clash service
  5
  6 Clash=/usr/local/bin/clash
  7 CfgDir=/etc/clash/
  8
  9 stop(){
 10         if [ -n "$(pgrep clash)" ]
 11         then
 12                 for pid in $(pgrep clash)
 13                 do
 14                         kill $pid
 15                 done
 16         fi
 17 }
 18
 19 start(){
 20         nohup $Clash -d $CfgDir &!
 21 }
 22
 23 test -x $Clash || exit 0
 24
 25 case $1 in
 26   start)
 27         start
 28         ;;
 29
 30   stop)
 31         stop
 32         ;;
 33
 34   restart)
 35         stop
 36         start
 37         ;;
 38
 39   *)
 40         echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
 41         exit 1
 42 esac
 43
 44 exit 0
```

Comment: I suspect the ‘stop’ function is killing the init script as well as the executable.

Comment: If you have access to `pgrep`, you can let `pkill` from the same package do the killing for you instead of using a loop over pgrep output.

Comment: @jsbillings How can I check if it does that? I only know the way of debugging a script not a service.

Comment: @Wieland Tried that, it makes the code more tidier but the issue stays the same.

Comment: Run `bash -x /etc/init.d/clash restart` to see if it is actually doing anything, but if this is really buster, it might be running it as systemd instead, so it might be better to just write a systemd unit

Comment: @jsbillings Well, it's not a REAL buster, it's a "Linux Deploy" version(chroot version) which doesn't support systemd. I've done that  `bash -x`thing and the script works fine.